# Separate shopping list on Alexa

Tags: alexa

I share a Amazon prime account with another and we each have an Echo. Each Echo is setup with our respective accounts. When we ask Alexa to add something to our shopping list, both Echo's write to the same list. I know we can create separate lists with different names, but we don't want to be able to see each other's list. How can we have separate, private shopping lists.